# Remote desktop from any location to my Ubuntu PC

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, remote-desktop

I have configured remote desktop to connect from my laptop (Windows) to my PC (Ubuntu) using XRDP following [these](https://linuxconfig.org/ubuntu-20-04-remote-desktop-access-from-windows-10) instructions. So I can connect to my PC (Ubuntu) just from my local network.

Now what I want to do is to try to do the same from any location, I will travel to other country and I will need to connect from my laptop to my PC.

Is there any way to do it in a easy and free way? I was thinking to create my own VPN using openVPN, is that a right way? I would like to take advantage of the remote desktop connection that I have already configured.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One way is to use a software tool such as Teamviewer which has a Linux version https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/linux/ I think it's still free for personal use. Confusingly they have 2 products TeamViewer AND TeamViewer Host. I would check what does what before installing either.

Answer (score 1):

You can tunnel RDP over ssh.

1. On the PC, `apt install openssh-server`
2. I recommend disabling the password authentication and using public key authentication only. Follow [these instructions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys-on-ubuntu-1804) to generate a keypair on your laptop, and copy the public key to your PC. Then add the line `PasswordAuthentication no` to your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and run `sudo service ssh reload`. You can skip this step and just use your password to authenticate, but be warned, you will face regular brute force cracking attempts on the Internet.
3. When connecting with `ssh` from your laptop to the PC, add a port forwarding option like this:

`ssh -L3389:localhost:3389 <address_of_PC>`

Once the connection is established, you will be able to connect your RDP client on the laptop to `localhost:3389`. `ssh` will be listening there, and forward everything over the secure connection.

Using this method you do not need or want to open the 3389 port in your PC's firewall, because as far as the RDP server is concerned the connection will be coming from `localhost` (the `ssh` server). Only port 22 needs to be open, for `ssh`.

edit: Sorry, don't know how I missed that your laptop is running Windows. If you are using a command line `ssh` client there, it probably works the same way as above. If you are using PuTTy, you can set up port forwarding there using [these instructions](https://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_putty.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer Nathan, is not better to set up a VPN, connect to that VPN and then use Remote Desktop? Thank you!

Comment: A VPN is a perfectly good option, but I think `ssh` is much easier to set up and, provided you disable passwords as detailed in step #2, as secure as it gets. A VPN is more complex to set up, which means more opportunities to make mistakes that could compromise security. For example, because your RDP service only needs to listen on `localhost`, there is no need to worry about routing tables, or firewall rules, etc. Personally, I would use `ssh` for your use case and only consider setting up a VPN if the former proved inadequate in some way.

Comment: To clarify the last part a bit, an example would be if you wanted access to ten different RDP servers instead of just one. You can still use `ssh` there, forwarding ten different ports, but some would consider that cumbersome. In such a situation you might prefer to set up a VPN instead.